# How can I get these two classes to function properly? C++

Tags: c++, class, constructor, virtual-functions

I have two classes defined as follows:

```
class Color
{
public:
    GamePiece* pieces[16]; //ERROR HERE
    char map[8][8] = {};

    Color();
    virtual ~Color(); 

    virtual void getCurrentLocations() = 0;
};

class GamePiece
{
public:
    char id = 'a';
    int current_location[1][2] = {};

    GamePiece();
    virtual ~GamePiece();

    virtual bool checkLegalMove(Color* oppColorPieces, int a, int b) = 0;
    bool canAttackSqaure(Color* oppColorPieces, int rowIndex, int colIndex);
};
```

When I try to run the program, I get an error saying there is an unexpected token preceding ';' on the marked line.
When I reduce this problem to the following classes, it works fine.

```
class A
{
public:
    B* pieces[16];
    char map[8][8];
    A(); 
    ~A();
};

class B
{
public:
    int a;
    B();
    bool checkLegalMove(A* temp, int a, int b);
    bool canAttackSqaure(A* oppColorPieces, int rowIndex, int colIndex);    
};
```

So, I am guessing it is a problem with the virtual functions, but I do not know what. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Please use `std::array` from the header `array`, since this is C++

Comment: Please learn about *forward declarations*. When you try to build (not run) the compiler doesn't know what `GamePiece` is when you attempt to use that symbol.

Comment: Define "works fine", because the second code sample suffers from [*exactly* the same problem](https://godbolt.org/z/cTcfT5b3v) as the first: an unknown type name encountered. And frankly I question the design in the first place. A `Color` *really* needs a collection of `GamePiece` pointers? That `Color` class seems more like a `Board` than a color.

Comment: *When I try to run the program...* -- No, you are *compiling* the program.  There is no program to run, because the build was unsuccessful.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank you, I was unaware that you could forward declare classes.

Comment: The most obvious is that you must forward declare `GamePiece` identifier to tell compiler this is a class. The second example should not work better than the first one.

Comment: @WhozCraig: At least as I read it, `Color` is more like `Player`. That is, it's keeping track of all of one player's pieces, and we'd expect to see exactly two `Color` objects in a typical game.